# Background video pushing outside parent div

Tags: html, css

Experiencing a problem where under a certain window width (around 1100px)
the background video of the title page of my site begins to cause problems. its hard to explain, but an inexplicable gap appears between the first div (titlecontainer) and the one below (aboutcontainer).
The test server address is: mintrain . co . uk

any help would be great. i've read up on simulating background-size: cover for html5 video but it doesn't solve this issue where the div height is finite. thanks, Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the position be absolute make the position fixed. And that should fix your sizing issue!

```
#bgvideo {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: #232528;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
#bgvideo {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: #232528;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
} }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Jade! works great all the way until browser width hits 431px.

Comment: I will take another look at it!

Comment: I added a media rule, this probably isn't the best way to get it working but it solves the 2 issues. @JackScott